# Is there a way in SQL Server to force use of a particular server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

This is not to be confused with "USE Database"

I work in a company that has many servers, and analysts are always asking if there is a way to force the use of a particular server because we often have queries open which access multiple servers, and SSMS gets confused.  Currently, the only way to unconfuse SSMS is to close and re-open things, and no one likes having to do that in the middle of productivity.

Comment: `SSMS gets confused`. I doubt it. I suspect your analysts are the ones getting confused...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables `USE <DatabaseName>` doesn't work because he's not trying to distinguish between databases in a single server, he's trying to distinguish between databases in different servers (some of which may have the same database name).  Same reason why he can't just use standard `[]` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there is a way.

1. *Right click* in the body of the query
2. Under the "Connection" submenu, select "*Change Connection*"
3. Profit!

[image: Menu Detai]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict SSMS in this manner, though you have some options to mitigate mistakes:

- Ensure your analysts log into the different servers using different user names that have appropriate restrictions setup on them, so they can't use one where they shouldn't.
- Install the [SQL Server Power Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features) - one feature will color tabs. Each color will correspond to a connected server.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I believe you may want to have your network admins look into setting up an alternate pipe. See [SQL Server to Listen on an Alternate Pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189321.aspx) ...

However, I don't think there's an option to 'hot swap' an open connection to a different network IP with SSMS open...

Answer (score 0):

Link your servers under server objects, linked servers.  Then you can refer to each server in your queries. linkedserver.db.dbo.table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).